# Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function - when self invoking function is at the bottom of the script

Tags: jquery

The code snippet is the reproducible portion of larger code. Here if i write the self invoking function at the bottom, it gives me "Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function" but if i move that to top, it works. Can any one please help me understand why this error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var height = $(window).height();
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                $('.status').html(scrollTop)
            });
        });

        (function(a){
                console.log(a);
        }("sometext"));
     
             
    </script>
 
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="status"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't reproduce the error. But if you leave out the `;` before the self-invoking function, you get the error. It's treating the parentheses around the self-invoking function as the argument list of the `$(...)` expression.

Comment: So check your real code, and make sure you have a semicolon at the end of `$(function() ...)`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, that exactly what i has missed.